# OpenGL - Renderer Design

Tags: c++, opengl, stdvector

I have a more or less general question regarding the design of an opengl-renderer in c++. At the moment my renderer does just iterate over a vector, containing all models, that are in my scene. But now, my scenes are growing. Basically for each frame, a `std::vector` of pointers to all models has to exist. Now my question is, how to efficiently alter this std::vector, if this vector gets really long.

What are efficient methods for this? What if I want to remove or add pointers to this vector? Should I alter the exisiting vector or should I just create a new one, what is faster? How do I manage to find and remove an pointer from this vector in a fast way if the vector is really long? Should I do all this in a separate thread?

Comment: why do you need to redefine that vector each frame?

Comment: No, it does not. I did clarify the question.

Comment: If you don't care about order, you can quickly erase an element from the middle of a vector by swapping it with the last element and calling `pop_back()`.

Comment: Actually, I learnt the trick described by @gan_ in an SGI doc. as a hint to speed up realtime 3d rendering (although it can be applied to any topic if suitable).